# Auto loading routes in HapiJS

Tags: node.js, rest, hapi.js

I was wondering if anyone has a way to automatically and programmatically load HapiJS routes automatically. I was looking for a way that would be something like the routes that fall under a specific resource all go in a js file named after that resource.

For example, if I had a file `src/routes/account.js`, which would have the routes `/login` and `/register`, which would create the API routes `/account/login` and `/login/register`.. Or something that would let me have a programmatic way of automatically loading the routes.

I use [Actin](https://github.com/thegoleffect/actin) to load my controllers, and I was hoping to use something similar to that. I didn't see any [plugins](http://hapijs.com/plugins) that could accomplish this, so I thought id ask if someone has a method for this already

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you're looking for since I don't make a distinction between routes and controllers in my hapi projects, but this is what I use to load my routes: https://gist.github.com/mikefrey/66cce57d1fdd78a87b32
You'd likely have to modify it for your own usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that would load routes programmatically, using a folder structure to help with the route hierarchy, so I created my own.

It's not a full HapiJS plugin yet, but [heres the code](https://github.com/jhyland87/hapijs-autoroute) if anyone wants to use it.

#### Basic Details

1. Load the **[routes.js](https://github.com/jhyland87/hapijs-autoroute/blob/master/src/routes.js)** file as a HapiJS plugin (from the **/dist** folder, for ES5 transpiled version)

   - You can load it any way you want, I use [Confidence](https://github.com/hapijs/confidence) to load it in the [configuration file](https://github.com/jhyland87/hapijs-autoroute/blob/master/src/confidence.json#L23-L29)
2. Create a *[Routes folder](https://github.com/jhyland87/hapijs-autoroute/tree/master/src/routes) to contain your routes, make sure it's in the same folder as the **routes.js** file (Ill make an option so you can specify the routes folder later)
3. Create some js files that export some HapiJS routes ([like so](https://github.com/jhyland87/hapijs-autoroute/blob/master/src/routes/root.js)).

   - Keep in mind that the `path` in the route files will be appended to the path from the `routes` folder. Meaning if you have a file at `src/routes/users.js`, and it has a route with the path `/list`, then the real path will be `/users/list`
   - To define a **Root Resource**, then define the `rootResource` in the [settings](https://github.com/jhyland87/hapijs-autoroute/blob/master/src/confidence.json#L26-L28) (Value should be the file name without the `.js` extension)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hapi-auto-route](https://github.com/sitrakay/hapi-auto-route). This package loads routes automatically and add prefix to the route path